# OpenGL won't interpret attributes correctly when trying to apply textures

Tags: opengl, textures, vertex-attribute

I'm going through [open.gl](http://open.gl/) tutorials. I'm at the point where I want to apply textures. The tutorial first introduces texture coordinates to the `vertices[]` array, and then adding the corresponding `in`, `out` and `uniform` variables accordingly on each shader. The issue I'm having with is OpenGL cannot interpret the vertex attributes correctly with the given stride and offset parameters when I change the structure of the `vertices[]` array, as seen on the second half of the code below.

```
float vertices[] =
{//   X      Y     R     G     B
    -0.5f, +0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
    +0.5f, +0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
    +0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};

GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(_shaderProgram.program, "position");  // handle to vert shader argument
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
    5 * sizeof(float), 0); // how to interpret input array
// position, vec2, type, normalize mode, stride, offset             

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(_shaderProgram.program, "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));

 // Draw call
 glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

---

**vert.glsl**

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec3 Color;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**frag.glsl**

```
#version 150

in vec3 Color;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
}
```

[image]

---

However, when I want to introduce texture coordinates in the `vertices[]` array like this, I get weird shapes. OpenGL for some reason cannot interpret the `vertices[]` array correctly.

```
float vertices[] =                      
{//   X      Y       R     G     B       S     T
    -0.5f, +0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f      // Top-left
    +0.5f, +0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f      // Top-right
    +0.5f, -0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f      // Bottom-right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f      // Bottom-left
};

GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(_shaderProgram.program, "position");  // handle to vert shader argument
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 
    7 * sizeof(float), 0); // how to interpret input array
                // position, vec2, type, normalize mode, stride, offset

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(_shaderProgram.program, "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    7 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));

GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(_shaderProgram.program, "texcoords");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
    7 * sizeof(float), (void*)(5 * sizeof(float)));

 // Draw call (same as before)
 glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

---

**vert.glsl**

```
#version 150

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
in vec2 texcoords;

out vec3 Color;
out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
    Color = color;
    TexCoord = texcoords;

    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

**frag.glsl**

```
#version 150

in vec3 Color;
in vec2 TexCoord;

out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
    // i know the pixel color computation doesn't make sense here, as I also 
    // do not provide the texture uniform variable. But I'm aware of the 
    // glsl compiler optimizations stripping away unused attributes, so here 
    // I use it in a meaningless way so that its not optimized out. I just 
    // want to make sure the interpretation of the vertex attributes are 
    // correct, so that I can start getting the texture right on the correct geometry.
    outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0) + texture(tex, TexCoord);
}
```

[image]

---

From the output I get, I conclude that OpenGL somehow having hard time interpreting the vertex array with the given attribute stride and offset parameters. What causes this - what am I missing - and how do I get this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [/u/slime73](https://www.reddit.com/user/slime73) pointed out, you are missing `,` after your `T` coordinates.

```
float vertices[] =                      
{//   X      Y       R     G     B       S     T
    -0.5f, +0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f     // Top-left
    +0.5f, +0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f      // Top-right
    +0.5f, -0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f      // Bottom-right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f      // Bottom-left
};
```

should be

```
float vertices[] =                      
{//   X      Y       R     G     B       S     T
    -0.5f, +0.5f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,     // Top-left
    +0.5f, +0.5f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,     // Top-right
    +0.5f, -0.5f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,     // Bottom-right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,     // Bottom-left
};                                           //   ^ commas.
```